# Adding external javascript link in static blocks

Tags: blocks, javascript, link

I'm creating a static block to show custom menus and calling this static block inside topmenu.phtml. Now I want to write some javascript code which will be applied on the ids/classes present in that static block. How I can link my static block to js file where I can write my js/jquery code? I've tried this way but it didn't work.

```
<script  src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js');?>"></script>
<script  src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/myfile.js');?>"></script>
```

Comment: you want to include script in static block?

Comment: Not sure I understand correctly, but do you mean you want to include JS files in a static block that's created in the admin panel of Magento?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the skin URL in cms page/static block.

```
{{skin url="your-path"}}
```

So now you can add script like below.

```
<script src="{{skin url="your-path"}}"></script>
```

Or else you can directly add script with in script tag